Why Digispark can be a HID but Arduino Uno/Nano can't?
I tried to make a project with a Nano as a head which was based on a V-USB-like library EasyHID. For unknown reasons this try was unsuccessfull and I couldn't make the Nano run correctly. It's normal: guys wrote, this venture has lesser 50% success because 328p works at the edge of its capabilities when emulate USB protocol.
Later I found that some people uses Digispark as base of their HID projects and it is more stable than Nano. Please explain what are the key differences that make the Attiny win in HID projects? And besides is there a way to recieve signals from 8 and more buttons (analog keyboard?) when P4 and P3 are busy as USB+ and USB-?
P.S. I have no Digispark yet for tests so this interest is hypothetical. This board has very limited functionality so I doubt that I will be able to apply it in other projects.

why do you want to use virtual USB? Arduino Micro/Leonardo has native USB peripheral

@Juraj I'm lookig for cheap and supercompact solution

Micro is as small as Nano

You could use a multi-channel analogue to digital converter, connected to the Attiny via I2C. The ad7606 would give you 8 separate analogue inputs, using just two pins to connect to the I2C bus. As an alternative you could use an ADS1115. This again is an analogue to digital converter chip. It only has 4 channels, but you can connect two to the same I2C bus to give you 8 input channels. The ADS1115 is available on ebay in a neat breadboard-compatible package.
I have rechecked your suggestion of using a PCF8574P. This is not in fact an analogue to digital converter, but an IO bus expander - which means that it gives you 8 digital input/output pins (not analogue). This part is out of producion, but has the advantage that it is a DIP package, so is easy to breadboard.
As to your question about what board to use for HID devices, the Arduino Nano does not have a built-in USB controller, so it cannot be used to emulate a USB device, but the ATtiny85 and the Arduino Leonardo do.

I guess, an I/O bus expander is more suitable in my case, seems it is easier to use with a 16k matrix keyboard I have. And may be you can answer first question about hardware specificity too?

I have added a bit to my answer re the ATtiny and the Nano - and yes - it sounds like you would be better off with a bus expander rather than a multi-channel A to D converter.

In response to the headline question 'Why Digispark can be a HID but Arduino Uno/Nano can't?', the main difference is that the ATtiny85 processor on the DigiSpark is directly connected to the computer via USB, while the Nano/Uno have another chip in between.
The second chip on the Uno/Nano is programmed to be a USB-serial device, so the Uno/Nano cannot be a HID device without reprogramming that chip.
The Nicohood firmware (no affiliation, this is just one example I have heard of) https://github.com/NicoHood/HID is a project that aims to add features to Uno boards by upgrading the firmware on the USB-serial chip on an Uno.
Note that not all USB-serial chips can be upgraded; the ones that I understand are supported are the ATmega16u2 versions.
